# R: Dropping columns with names containing a substring anywhere except the start using regular expressions in dplyr

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I am trying to use `dplyr` to drop columns from a `data.frame` where the column name contains a substring anywhere except the start of the name (i.e. any index other than the first).

After looking around (pun intended), it appears that this is usually accomplished by including a lookbehind assertion in the regular expression I pass to `dplyr::matches()` within the `dplyr::select()` call. I'm not familiar with how these work, but my attempt at implementing this below throws an error.

Am I incorrectly implementing a lookbehind or is this a limitation of the regular expressions I can pass to `matches()`? I welcome a working solution.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Example data
df <- data.frame(bar = rnorm(1),
                 foo1 = rnorm(1),
                 bar_foo1 = rnorm(1),
                 bar_foo1_bat = rnorm(1))

# Desired output
df %>% select(bar, foo1)
#>        bar       foo1
#> 1 1.057651 -0.1526598

# Sucessfully drops columns with "foo1" anywhere
df %>% select(-matches(".*foo1.*"))
#>        bar
#> 1 1.057651

# Both fail to drop columns with "foo1" anywhere *except the start of the string*

df %>% select(-matches("(?<!^).*foo1.*"))
#> Warning in grep(needle, haystack, ...): TRE pattern compilation error 'Invalid
#> regexp'
#> Error in `select()`:
#> ! invalid regular expression '(?<!^).*foo1.*', reason 'Invalid regexp'

df %>% select(-matches("(?<!^)foo1.*"))
#> Warning in grep(needle, haystack, ...): TRE pattern compilation error 'Invalid
#> regexp'
#> Error in `select()`:
#> ! invalid regular expression '(?<!^)foo1.*', reason 'Invalid regexp'
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one or more of `.` at the beginning so you could write `^.{1,}`.

```
df %>% dplyr::select(-matches("^.{1,}foo1"))
#         bar       foo1
# 1 -1.077056 -0.5649875
```

Comment: This is a more flexible solution. Is it redundant to add an anchor to the start of the regex: `("^.{1,}foo1.*") `

Comment: @user3614648 No it's important, the text was right, just forgot it in the code. We can do without the `.*` at the end though.

Answer (score 1):

```
df%>%select(-matches('^.+foo1'))
       bar       foo1
1 1.806521 -0.9380235
```